# Django: Search Function If No Initial Data

Tags: python, django

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    ....
    ....
    return render(request, 'search.html', {'list': list})
```

form looks like this,

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'new:search' %}">
   <input type="text" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Everything is working fine here but if a user simply press the "Search" button it shows all data instead of doing nothing.

So, how can I make this search function do nothing when user directly press the Search button without entering initial data?

Comment: You need to have some kind of if statement to inspect **query**.  If it’s an appropriate search term then let the search continue.  If it’s empty then do not perform the search.

Comment: put all the def function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the function you've provided, `list` must be "all the data" and therefore you need to return without that.

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', None)
    if not q:
        return render(request, 'search.html', {'list': []})
    else:
        ....
    return render(request, 'search.html', {'list': list})
```

Comment: Wow, working perfectly fine. Thank you very much sir :)